Delete line containing pattern in between specific range of lines
I want to completely remove lines containing a pattern ignoring first few lines. I tried:
$ sed -i '2,$s/pattern/d' file.txt

but it says unterminated's' command.
For example I have a file:
pattern # important one, not to be removed

some line1
some line2

pattern some content

another line3

pattern another content

another line4

So, I want
pattern # important one, not to be removed

some line1
some line2


another line3


another line4

If I use sed -i '2,$s/pattern//' file.txt then it doesn't completely remove the line, there are characters that aren't in pattern, even though it must be removed.

Use awk 'NR==1{print};NR>1 && !/pattern/' file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt

You can negate the line range, w/a ! like this: sed '1,5!{/8/d}' <(seq 1 10)

The easiest way to do this in sed would probably be to skip the lines you want to ensure cannot be affected, instead of selecting the lines you want to consider, and then sub-selecting within those the ones you actually want to delete.  Example:
sed '1b;/pattern/d' file.txt

Explanation:
That's two independent rules , separated by a semicolon (;).

The first has address 1, which selects line 1 by line number, and command b, which, in this form, ends the current sed cycle and starts a new one.  sed's default behavior is to print its pattern space at the end of each cycle, before reading the next line, so this just passes the first line through.

The second has address /pattern/, which selects the lines you want to delete from among those not already skipped.  Of course, the d command deletes them.


You could use any kind of address with the b command, not just line number, and you could put any number of them at the start of the sed expression to exclude diverse lines based on different criteria.

1!/pattern/d slightly pithier though less extensible to an actual range.

The s command is for "search and replace", and you're missing the replace part.
The d command takes a pattern. Two specify 2 patterns, use a {...} block.
For example, from the numbers 1 to 20, delete numbers containing 3 or 8, but only between numbers 5 to 15
seq 20 | sed '5,15{/[38]/d;}'

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9      <<< "8" removed
10
11
12
14     <<< "13" removed
15
16
17
18
19
20


Use this Perl one-liner:
perl -i.bak -ne 'if ( $. > 1 ) { next if /pattern/ } print;' file.txt

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
-e : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
-n : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to $_ by default.
-i.bak : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension .bak. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use -i and skip the extension.
$. : Current input line number.
See also:

perldoc perlrun: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches
perldoc perlvar: Perl predefined variables


Why not just print if $.>1 && /pattern/ ? - the efficiency is the same.

@stevesliva This way, it is a little easier to change for more complex conditions. For example, to refine the conditions further, use if ( $. > 1 || ( $. > 10 && $. < 20 ) ) { next if /pattern/ && !/pattern2/ } print;

Just use awk:
$ awk 'NR<2 || !/pattern/' file
pattern # important one, not to be removed

some line1
some line2


another line3


another line4

or if you prefer a positive condition:
$ awk 'NR>1 && /pattern/{next} {print}' file
pattern # important one, not to be removed

some line1
some line2


another line3


another line4


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/pattern/{1b;d}' file

If a line contains pattern and it is not the first line, delete it.
Or if you prefer:
sed '/pattern/{2,$!b;d}' file

If you are interested in only deleting pattern lines after the first such line, use:
sed '/pattern/{x;//d;g}' file

This uses the hold space (a separate register) as a flag.
